# Determining the number of matches between 2 sets of numbers , PHP

Tags: php

Thanks for any help provided :)

so i have 2 sets of numbers:

```
$num1win , $num2win, $num3win, $num4win, $num5win, $num6win
```

and

```
$num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6
```

and i am using the following code to try to match them:

```
$match=0;
$match += match($num1win, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6);
$match += match($num2win, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6);
$match += match($num3win, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6);
$match += match($num4win, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6);
$match += match($num5win, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6);
$match += match($num6win, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6);

function match($win, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6){
    $my_array = array_flip(array($num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6));
    if (isset($my_array[$win])){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

this looks good to me but my results are very strange, the results give me a match (only 1) if the numbers matching are $num1win and ($num1, or $num2) OR  $num2win and ($num1, or $num2) but nothing else

could someone please let know of a mistake or if they have a cleaner way of getting the job done

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just try [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)?

Comment: Works for me when values for each number are explicitly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another possible solution that compares numbers to winning numbers and returns the total number of matches:

```
<?php
// Make one array out of all the winning numbers:
$winners = array($num1win, $num2win, $num3win, $num4win, $num5win, $num6win);
// Make a second array out of all the other numbers:
$numbers = array($num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, $num5, $num6);
// Display the results:
print match_count($winners, $numbers);

/**
 * @return
 *  Total number of matches.
 */
function match_count($winners, $numbers) {
  return count(array_intersect($numbers, $winners));
}
```

Comment: Isn't your loop just `$match_count = count($results)`?